# Angular Ant Design DatePicker default mode

Tags: angular, antd, ng-zorro-antd

I am using the Ant Design for Angular library and I am wondering if it is possible to use the `datepicker` component specifying a default mode for the calendar view.

Specifically I would like my datepicker to open in "year" mode such as illustrated by the following screenshot

[image]

After selecting the year, you should be prompted with month and than finally date selection.
From the [docs](https://ng.ant.design/components/date-picker/en) it looks like they have a `year-picker`, but - as the name describes - only allows to select a particular year, without having the possibility of selecting month and date. Do you know of any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `nz-date-picker` has a `nzMode` property which can be one of `'decade' | 'year' | 'month' | 'date' | 'time'`. In this case, you can change the `nzMode` on triggering `(nzOnPanelChange)`.

I wrote the code below to meet your case:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'nz-demo-date-picker-mode',
    template: `
    <nz-date-picker
      [nzMode]="mode"
      [(ngModel)]="value"
      (nzOnOpenChange)="handleDateOpenChange($event)"
      (nzOnPanelChange)="handleDatePanelChange($event)"
    >
    </nz-date-picker>
  `
})
export class NzDemoDatePickerModeComponent {
    public value: Date;
    public mode = 'year';

    handleDateOpenChange(open: boolean): void {
        if (!open && this.mode === 'date') {
            this.mode = 'year'; // back to year
        }
    }

    handleDatePanelChange(mode: string): void {
        switch (this.mode) {
            case 'year':
                this.mode = 'month'; // next to pick month
                break;
            case 'month':
                this.mode = 'date'; // next to pick date
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        console.log('handleDatePanelChange: ', this.mode);
    }

}
```